# JS if statement wont work

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Just using a normal if-statement to check if something is equal or higher/lower than the actual result.

Only getting the else alert..

```
function generatePrice(b){
  var i;
  var a = [];
  var c = 24;
  var deg = Math.floor(360/c);
  var prev_deg=0;

  for(i=1; i < 25; i++){
      var tmp_deg = i * deg;
      a[i] = {'begin':prev_deg,'end':tmp_deg};
  prev_deg =  tmp_deg + 1;

  }

  if(a[22].begin >= b && a[22].end <= b){
    alert("u WON");
  }
  if(a[6].begin >= b && a[6].end <= b){
    alert("u WON");
  }
  if(a[13].begin >= b && a[13].end <= b){
    alert("u WON");
  }
  else {
    alert("Better luck next time");
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `begin` and `end`?

Comment: maybe the conditions are all false?

Comment: Please post **all** of the relevant code so that we can help you.

Comment: I will edit and add the full code

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us the data that your logic is working off of.

Comment: Even after the edit, you don't tell us what number you pass in that becomes `b`, so how can we help you?

Comment: Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. Observe what exactly `b` is and what each condition returns.

Comment: Your `>=` and `<=` need to be reversed and you need to add `else if` to the first `if` statements. See this **[working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uf8onzca/14/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need a switched check

```
begin <= b <= end
```

where `b` is inside of the interval. Then you need to exit the function

```
if (a[22].begin <= b && b <= a[22].end) {
    alert('Won!');
    return;
}
if (a[6].begin <= b && b <= a[6].end) {
    alert('Won!');
    return;
}
if (a[13].begin <= b && b <= a[13].end) {
    alert('Won!');
    return;
}
alert('Sorry!');
```

or to chain the conditions with else

```
if (a[22].begin <= b && b <= a[22].end) {
    alert('Won!');
} else if (a[6].begin <= b && b <= a[6].end) {
    alert('Won!');
} else if (a[13].begin <= b && b <= a[13].end) {
    alert('Won!');
} else {
    alert('Sorry!');
}
```

```js
function generatePrice(b) {
    var i;
    var a = [];
    var c = 24;
    var deg = Math.floor(360 / c);
    var prev_deg = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
        var tmp_deg = i * deg;
        a[i] = { 'begin': prev_deg, 'end': tmp_deg };
        prev_deg = tmp_deg + 1;
    }
    
    if (a[22].begin <= b && b <= a[22].end ) {
        alert("u WON");
        return;
    }
    if (a[6].begin <= b && b <= a[6].end ) {
        alert("u WON");
        return;
    }
    if (a[13].begin<= b &&  b <=a[13].end) {
        alert("u WON");
        return;
    }
    alert("Better luck next time");
}

generatePrice(80);
```

Comment: Still won't work..

Comment: I've tried both things but it still won't display the alert